# Run forms Application through command prompt and send commands to it

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line

I have a windows forms tool in VB that i have been working on for a while now. 
Now i would like to be able to access all of the controls and return values through the command prompt so that i am able to play with it through Azure and basically make the application a black box.

So this is how i went about thinking i should do it.

1 - In my project, i created a second solution, a C# Windows Command line framework.

2 - i than added the following script to that second project in order to run the win forms

```
using EnabledTest;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Command_lineStartup
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static frmMain MainForm;

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                // Command line given, display console

            }
            else
            {
                AllocConsole();
                ConsoleMain(args);
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(MainForm = new frmMain());
                GUI(); 
            }
        }

        private static void ConsoleMain(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command line = {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
            for (int ix = 0; ix < args.Length; ++ix)
                Console.WriteLine("Argument{0} = {1}", ix + 1, args[ix]);
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        public static void GUI()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing version 1 :");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Project File path to open, Project must be a .mmp file");
            string Path = Console.ReadLine();
            MainForm.LoadProject(Path);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not think this is the right way. When i run the console application through CMD using C:\TFS\Enabled Test\Command-lineStartup\bin\Debug\Command-lineStartup.exe"

I does not behave how i want it to work.

So my question is.
Am i going about this the right way? if so what am i doing wrong here

is there an easier way?

Comment: To Clarify, it does not do what i want it to do because i does not call GUI() until the forms application is closed.

Comment: `Application.Run()` is a blocking call, thus why your `GUI()` method doesn't run until the form is closed. Create a new **THREAD** and call `Application.Run()` from inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a way in the end. When running the application through CMD, the arguments that are supplied can be accessed using

```
 Dim cla As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

then for each of the arguments provided u can do something with it. 
For example,

```
 If cla.Length > 1 Then
        'cla(0) is the executable path.
        'cla(1) is the Path to the project
        If Not IsIDE() Then WCLicenseIsLicensed("Application", True)
        Me.Text = Application.ProductName
        mblnLoaded = True

        LoadProject(cla(1))

        TreeVieuwSystem.Nodes(cla(2)).Expand()
        TreeVieuwSystem.SelectedNode = TreeVieuwSystem.Nodes(cla(2)).Nodes.Find(cla(2) & "\" & cla(3), True).First
        NodeSelected()
        If cla(2) = "Test Plans" Then
            TheWindowThatAllowsYouToEditTheObject.RunTestPlan()
        ElseIf cla(2) = "Tests" Then
            TheWindowThatAllowsYouToEditTheObject.RunTest(False)
        End If
    Else
```